# PDF Long Term Validation (LTV) for existing signed PDF

Tags: pdf, signature, signing, digital

I have a digitally signed PDF without Long Term validation (LTV) and the user certificate does not have any URL in the CRL Distribution Points whereas the sub CA  certificate and CA certificates have CRL URL in the CRL distribution points. When I tried creating LTV for the existing PDF by adding the CRLs of Sub CA and CA, the Acrobat reader still says "Document is not LTV enabled" in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC v2018.011.20038.

Using the same code, When I tried adding LTV to another signed PDF containing CRLs for user certificate as well as sub CA and CA certificates. Acrobat Reader says the document is LTV enabled.

Does this mean, if the user certificate does not have CRL Distribution Point, then LTV cannot be enabled?

Comment: Does the user certificate merely not mention how to retrieve revocation information for it while the CA does offer CRLs or OCSP responders? Or are there really no means to do so at all? In the latter case the signature cannot be LTV enabled. In the former case you might manually have to help, probably implementing a small program to add a manually retrieved CRL to the document.

Comment: There is no mean to do so. The CRL Distribution Point of the user certificate is as follow:  [1]CRL Distribution Point
     Distribution Point Name:
          Full Name:
               Directory Address:
                    CN=CRL460
                    CN=ABC Solutions sub-CA for eSign 2016
                    OU=Sub-CA
                    O=ABC Limited
                    C=IN

Comment: If there are no revocation information available for the end entity certificates, that PKI requires non-standard approaches to validation etc. Thus, mechanisms and states based on the standards don't apply. In particular Adobe's term "LTV-enabled" does not apply.

Comment: @mkl, Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.